# How to output row count calculations in Oracle's SQL*Plus

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am using SQL*Plus with Oracle 11.2 and I know how to output the count of rows adhering to some condition, e.g.:

```
select count(*) from MY_TABLE where MY_FIELD is not null;
```

Also it is easy to output all rows in MY_TABLE:

```
select count(*) from MY_TABLE;
```

However, **how can I output in SQL*Plus the ratio of the two counts, i.e. how can I do in SQL*Plus a calculation on the output from SQL commands?**.

---

**Some notes**:

1. I am interested in this because I have a long-running background process which updates the values in the `MY_FIELD` column over time from `null` to a text, so it would be nice to see quickly in SQL*Plus what ratio of rows is already done.
2. I tried

   ```
   (select count(*) from MY_TABLE where MY_FIELD is not null) / (select count(*) from MY_TABLE);
   ```

   but this obviously does not work because it isn't a proper SQL command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count(<expression>)` will only count rows where `<expression>` isn't `NULL` unless `<expression>` is `*` -- then it counts any rows. So you can use:

```
SELECT count(my_field)
       /
       count(*)
       FROM my_table;
```

But if the other process filling in the values runs in only one transaction and doesn't `COMMIT` every once in a while -- you didn't mention that --, you won't see any changes until it's done and finally `COMMIT`s.

Comment: `COUNT(my_field)` will return a count of non-NULL `my_field` values...

Comment: @Nick: Ah yeah, that's true. I somehow had in mind that they want to count `NULL`s, which was wrong of course... o_O Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @stickybit Works like a charm - in my particular case where the condition is `where MY_FIELD is not null`.

Comment: @stickybit BTW, the background process does commits every 1000 rows, so that the table is updated regularly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I didn't know the details here, just wanted to mentioned it *could* happen in general. But if it's not a possibility in Oracle, I removed the note.